# Undefined method `name' for #<Array:> in ActiveAdmin row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm using ActiveAdmin, here is my show page:

```
show do |product|
  attributes_table do
    row :name
    row :photos do
      @photos = product.photos
      @photos.each do |p|
        image_tag(p.photo)
      end
    end
  end
  active_admin_comments
end
```

I get this error: `undefined method name' for #<Array:>`

it's on this line:

```
@photos = product.photos
```

Why and how? I dont even have `name` in Photo.

### UPDATE

When I'm selecting one photo—for example the first photo of the product—it works! Really weird.

### UPDATE

It was only resetting the WEBRICK ... but now i encounter a new problem.
My photo holds the url is photo:string and when i'm using the code above it prints:

```
[#<Photo id: 1, created_at: "2012-08-31 20:34:15", updated_at: "2012-08-31 20:34:15", photo: "innoMicro.jpg", product_id: 3>]
```

And not the url only..

### UPDATE (WORKING SOLUTION!)

Here is my final and working code:

```
  show do |product|
    attributes_table do
      row :name
      row :description
      product.photos.each do |p|
        row :photo do
          image_tag(p.photo, :height => '256', :width => '256')
        end
      end
    end
    active_admin_comments
  end
```

The problem is that each photo has a new row.. can i keep them all in the same row?

Comment: The full stack trace from the error would be very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a first glance, 2 things don't look nice:

1. `@photos = product.photos`. Why the `@`? It's not like you need that instance variable anywhere else, and you might be inadvertently clashing with something that ActiveAdmin generated behind the curtains. So play it safe and just make it a local variable. Simplest way to do it: lose the `@`.
2. `image_tag(p.photo)` should become `image_tag(p.photo.url)`.

Correct these two and do tell us if it's fixed and if not, what's the new error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The error suddenly disapeared even without making your changes..
It was only resetting the WEBRICK...
but i dont have the p.photo.url doesn't exist.
each photo has a photo:string that represents the url.
but what's printed inside my row is: `[#<Photo id: 1, created_at: "2012-08-31 20:34:15", updated_at: "2012-08-31 20:34:15", photo: "innoMicro.jpg", product_id: 3>]`

Comment: We can theorize that you made an important change without restarting your dev webserver, then. Usually all kinds of strange errors can occur under such conditions and it's best one to go through several "make-sure" steps and then check for the error. -- I am glad you solved it. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is a typo or the real error but you wrote

```
product.images.all do |image|
    row :image do
        image_tag(image.image)
    end
end
```

Normally you should use 
    image_tag(image.url)

Hope this is your answer

Comment: Thank you, i updated.
but this was not the problem, The problem is that the image is not added to the product at all...